# Read binary file,cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: c, linux, binary

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILENAME "m_6"

int main() {
   float f;
   FILE * file;
   // read values
   if ( ! (file = fopen(FILENAME,"r")))
      return 1;
   while ( fread( &f, sizeof(float), 1, file ))
      printf("%e\n", f);
   fclose( file );
}
```

When I compile with gcc `gcc -c n1.c -o n1`

and try to run it I got

```
bash: ./n1: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

File m_6 and n1.c were executed on the same machine.

```
3.13.0-76-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You did not said how you generated the file "n1"

Comment: Sounds like your gcc installation is broken.  How exactly are you compiling the program?

Comment: Show your gcc command.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Take a look at edit please.

Comment: Cancel `-c` from command.

Comment: @LPs Thanks ,works now!

Comment: The question appears to be, why did you include that flag?

Comment: Yes, please tell us where that '-c' flag came from?

Comment: When you use `-c`, the output file is normally `n1.o`. You use this to compile each individual `.c` file to a `.o` file, which you plan on linking together with a later step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc `-c` compiles source files without linking.

Cancel `-c` from from command.